# Cant add background-image to webpage

Tags: html, css

Web developer noob here, only just starting off and kind of just playing around with things, but I've noticed I cannot insert a background-image into my webpage?

It's a tiny amount of code for now so I have inserted my HTML and and container relating to this below:

```css
body {
  font-family: fantasy;
  background-image: url(.\images\bumble);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Head Tag -->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>AJMascot/Homepage</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
    1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\style.css">
</head>

<!-- Body Tag-->

<body>

  <h1 style="color:rgb(255, 208, 0)">
    <bold>
      <center>AJ MASCOTS </center>
    </bold>
  </h1>

  <br>

  <h2 style="color:rgb(255, 208, 0)"><a href=".\AboutUs.html">About Us</a></h2>
  <h2 style="color:rgb(255, 208, 0)">Contact Us</h2>
  <h2 style="color:rgb(255, 208, 0)">Gallery</h2>
  <h2 style="color:rgb(255, 208, 0)"><a href=".\HomePage.html">Home</a></h2>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm also getting a 404 error in my browser as I use Visual Studios Live Server extension; when I run developer options if that has anything to do with the matter?

I can confirm that the file path for the picture is correct and the actual stylesheet link is correct as my font is pulling through onto the page.

Comment: I can't see where you are inserting a background image. Perhaps you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you make your code into something we can run to see the problem. Also just as an aside, tags like <center> are now deprecated, and do you want backslashes in your urls?

Comment: Use `/` instead of \ for paths; it's likely these are getting filtered out.

Comment: Are you sure that the file name is correct ? It appears you are referencing a file in a Win file system. a file extension is missing, which may be correct but also may just appear to be if file extensions are suppressed in the explorer. Note that the reference to the css file and to the image occur in different context, so to have one working does not necessarily imply the same for the other.

Comment: Here's an example of using forward slashes in `url(...)`: https://codepen.io/cuuupid/pen/YzeWmVW

Comment: since you are a beginner I will give you some side-notes. dont sue the HTML4 tags such as `bold` and `center`. Use CSS all along. Then dont put a `<br>` tag between block-level-elements. `<br>` is a linebreak for inline-elements. To space Block level elements apart you have `margin`

Answer (score -1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

We don’t use relative paths in URLs.
Your CSS doesn’t get loaded in the browser, load it properly.